# Grocery CRUD not sorting or searching results and set_model values are not paginated

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I’m using Grocery CRUD to display my search results. The results are displayed properly but the search and sort by columns doesn’t seem to be working.

Secondly ..im using the set_model to use my model to grab data..

```
function get_list()
{
    $name = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $progress=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT feeds.url,feeds.id,feeds.SalesID,sales_log.date, sales_log.sales_prob, sales_log.current_stage, sales_log.id AS logid FROM feeds LEFT JOIN sales_log ON sales_log.leadid = feeds.id WHERE feeds.SalesID = '$name' and feeds.archived = 0 ORDER BY sales_log.id DESC )a group by a.url order by logid desc");

    $results_array=$progress->result();

    return $results_array;        
}
```

The details are displayed inside the crud table but it displays all the records (574) within that page. The details are not being paginated. How can I display only 25 records and the others paginated? and also the sort/search functions arnt working

Can someone please suggest me how to fix these problems?

Comment: Have you added the JS and CSS files that are also created as part of the `render` call? See http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/create-crud-codeigniter-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the javascript console of your web browser. It sounds like you may not have linked to the Javascript correctly or something to that effect.